# What is the inclination angle in an Orthogonal rake system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining

In a single point cutting tool (right cut) what is the inclination angle ( lambda) in an Orthogonal rake system? I'm having difficulty in visualizing it. Please explain it in terms of ASA system.

[image]

Comment: Wow. All these years and nothing?